# key,value - how to handle null - python

Tags: python

My data is as below:

```
To: abc@gmail.com;def@gmail.com
CC: abc@hotmail.com;def@hotmail.com
BCC:
```

I am doing a key value split as below.

```py
key, value = line.split(": ")
```

the issue is, it is not able to handle the null value for BCC.I get the below error

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

I was wondering what is the best way to handle null while using the key value split?

Comment: Could try `key, value = [part.strip() for part in line.split(":")]` (note the use of ":" instead of ": ") or just store `line.split` in its own very and check if `len(split_result) == 2` before continuning.

Comment: You should use `":"` as the delimiter, not `": "`. There's no space after the `:` in the `BCC` line.

Comment: You could also not unpack your `key` and `value` at the time of assignment and do a check to see if there is a value or not. Or store in a dict instead.

Comment: the issue with changing to ";" from "; " is that sometines the value have a ":", which causes  unexpected splitting

Comment: Consider using the `email` module to parse the headers.

Comment: @chepner this was just a sample of data, there is data which are not emails having similar issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `str.split()`, use `str.partition()`. It always returns a 3-tuple of the text before the separator, the separator, and the text after the separator. If the separator is not found, there's no error raised, but the whole original string is in the first item, and the second and third items are empty strings.

```
key, _, value = line.partition(": ")
if not value:    # separator was not found
    print("no emails found")
```

Answer (score 2):

You should include a check on the size before you perform unpacking if you don't know its size in advance.

```py
data = """To: abc@gmail.com;def@gmail.com
CC: abc@hotmail.com;def@hotmail.com
BCC:"""

for line in data.split("\n"):
    result = line.split(": ")
    if len(result) == 2:
        [key, value] = result
        print(key, value)
    else:
        print("No emails found.")
```

prints

```
To abc@gmail.com;def@gmail.com
CC abc@hotmail.com;def@hotmail.com
No emails found.
```

Answer (score 1):

When the code doesn't find the string you passed in split, it returns an array with one item. That is why it cannot unpack two values.

Fixed code:

```
split_line = line.split(": ")
if len(split_line) > 1:
    key, value = line.split(": ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use the built in email parser

```
from email.parser import Parser

p = Parser()

data = """To: abc@gmail.com;def@gmail.com
CC: abc@hotmail.com;def@hotmail.com
BCC:"""

parsed = p.parsestr(data)

bcc = [e for e in parsed.get('BCC').strip().split(';') if not len(e) == 0]
print(
  'To:', parsed['To'].split(';'),
  '\nCC:', parsed['CC'].split(';'),
  '\nBCC', 'None' if not bcc else bcc
)
```